# SQL: Combining 'AS' and 'WHERE'

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a column that contains version numbers in 4 groups (i.e. `13.8.0.262` or `9.0.0.0`).

I have the following code that selects the version and splits it into the 4 groups and sorts it from oldest to newest

```
SELECT Version,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', 1 )*1 as A,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', 2 ),'.',-1)*1 as B, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', -2 ),'.',1)*1 as C,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', -1 )*1 as D
FROM Test
WHERE A > 13
order by 
A,B,C,D
```

I am trying to filter the results, i.e. search where the first version (A) is > 14 but I get `Unknown column 'A' in 'where clause'`. Am I using the `AS` keyword incorrectly?

Here is a link to my **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28647/14)**

Comment: The error message says about the `WHERE` clause but the query you posted doesn't have any.

Comment: Sorry, it was in the SQL Fiddle. I've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the `HAVING` clause useful:

```
SELECT Version,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', 1 )*1 as A,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', 2 ),'.',-1)*1 as B, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', -2 ),'.',1)*1 as C,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', -1 )*1 as D
FROM Test
HAVING A > 13
order by 
A,B,C,D
```

[Heres a working demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28647/17).

---

According to [MySQL SELECT documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), an alias cannot be accessed by a `WHERE` clause:

> It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

but it *can* be accessed by a `HAVING` clause:

> A HAVING clause can refer to any column or alias named in a select_expr in the SELECT list or in outer subqueries, and to aggregate functions.

Also note that:

> ... the SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. To accommodate both standard SQL and the MySQL-specific behavior of being able to refer columns in the SELECT list, MySQL 5.0.2 and up permit HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list, columns in the GROUP BY clause, columns in outer subqueries, and to aggregate functions.

For further reference, see [Why does MySQL allow HAVING to use SELECT aliases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/why-does-mysql-allow-having-to-use-select-aliases)

Comment: Thanks! Why is it `WHERE` does not see my `A` variable but `HAVING` does?

Comment: The MySQL documentation of the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) statement says: *"Do not use `HAVING` for items that should be in the `WHERE` clause."*

Comment: @axiac Yes, but it also says: "*MySQL 5.0.2 and up permit HAVING to refer to columns in the SELECT list*". However, I might prefer the method in your answer, depending on the context.

Comment: The recommendation I quoted is not about permissions, it's about the purpose of `HAVING` vs. `WHERE`. `WHERE` filters the rows selected into the result set, `HAVING` applies to the groups (or the aggregated data computed from these groups) generated by `GROUP BY`; it operates on a different level. Using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` has undesired effects sometimes. It seems they do the same thing if the query lacks the `GROUP BY` clause and it doesn't use aggregate functions.

Comment: @axiac Agreed, they have different purposes. I can see how WHERE may be more reliable, especially when aggregating data. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

An excerpt from the documentation of the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) MySQL statement:

> A *select_expr* can be given an alias using `AS alias_name`. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses.

And, a couple of paragraphs below:

> It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a `WHERE` clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the `WHERE` clause is executed.

#### The answer to your question

As mentioned in the fragments quoted above, no, you cannot use the `A` alias in the `WHERE` clause. You have to use the aliased expression instead.

```
SELECT Version,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', 1 )*1 as A,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', 2 ),'.',-1)*1 as B, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', -2 ),'.',1)*1 as C,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', -1 )*1 as D
FROM Test
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX( `version` , '.', 1 )*1 > 13
order by 
A,B,C,D
```

Comment: Nice solution. Out of curiosity, can performing `SUBSTRING_INDEX` again in the `WHERE` clause affect performance? It seems redundant, but maybe that's the best practice.